# Style WordPress search results based upon custom post type results

Tags: php, wordpress

On my site I have a few different custom post types which I have enabled to show up in search results. I was wondering how you could Query / Style each custom post type result differently.

For example if I was to do a search that pulled results from my blog articles and also my custom post type called cards which is a list of cards I would like to show my articles with their title and excerpt, but for my results for my cards I would like to be bale to show the title and the card image which I would call from a meta data field.

How exactly would this be done?
Would you have separate WP_Query's or would you use if statements inside of the default search loop? If so how do I tell if what custom post type the post is from.

This is the default loop i have for the WordPress search results.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <article>
        <h2><a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <time datetime="<?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date(); ?> <?php the_time(); ?></time> <?php comments_popup_link('Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </article>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by `$post->post_type`::

```
you can go through below code, just edit with your post types::

<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <?php
    if ($post->post_type == "cards") {
       //do fancy things


    }
    if ($post->post_type == "mycards") {
       //do fancy things


    }
    else {
       //otherwise just sit
    }

    <article>
        <h2><a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <time datetime="<?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date(); ?> <?php the_time(); ?></time> <?php comments_popup_link('Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </article>
    ?>

</li>
```

thanks

Comment: Thank you, will the order of which the custom post types appear in the results be based upon how I order the if statements?

Comment: No, it will order them in terms of the results.

Comment: agree with @StevenJones, if you want to show post according to your wishing order, you have to install one plugin and also add a line "order by" while fetching a post data.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use `if` conditions within `while` loop.

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<li>
    <?php
    if ($post->post_type == "card") {
       //do fancy things
    }
    else {
       //otherwise just sit
    }
    ?>
    <article>
        <h2><a href="<?php esc_url( the_permalink() ); ?>" title="Permalink to <?php the_title(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <time datetime="<?php the_time( 'Y-m-d' ); ?>" pubdate><?php the_date(); ?> <?php the_time(); ?></time> <?php comments_popup_link('Leave a Comment', '1 Comment', '% Comments'); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?>
    </article>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what i was looking for, I just wasn't sure how to tell which post type I was on. I will test this out soon and let you know how it works.

Comment: @RahilWazir i have improved your answer for both post types. you have given this only for one post type.